# How to get system scale factor on OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, scale, nswindow

I am working on an application and I need to get the scale factor used by the system.

So far, I have tried:

`[self.window backingScaleFactor];`from my view since I have read that `[[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor];` must be avoided.

However I am getting zero always.

Am I missing something? What does that zero mean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does the scale factor relate to DPI?

Comment: my bad. I mixed both concepts. What I need is the scale factor

Comment: Apparently it means your view doesn't have an associated window. [See this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2014-December/msg05296.html)